# CUDA simpleP2P failing

Tags: cuda, multi-gpu

I have Tesla M2070 cluster with 24 GPUs. I tried running simpleP2P SDK example but it is showing following error although my device supports UVA. OS; Linux 64bit.

`Checking for multiple GPUs...`

`CUDA-capable device count: 3`

> GPU0 = "    Tesla M2070" IS  capable of Peer-to-Peer (P2P)
>
> GPU1 = "    Tesla M2070" IS  capable of Peer-to-Peer (P2P)
>   GPU2 = "    Tesla M2070" IS  capable of Peer-to-Peer (P2P)

`Checking GPU(s) for support of peer to peer memory access...`

> Peer access from Tesla M2070 (GPU0) -> Tesla M2070 (GPU1) : No
>
> Peer access from Tesla M2070 (GPU1) -> Tesla M2070 (GPU0) : No

`Two or more SM 2.0 class GPUs are required for ./simpleP2P to run.`

`Support for UVA requires a GPU with SM 2.0 capabilities.`

`Peer to Peer access is not available between GPU0 <-> GPU1, waiving test.`

`PASSED`

It is showing PASSED at the end but peer access from one GPU to another flag is showing No value.

Comment: Peer to peer access requires that the GPUs are installed on the same PCI-e segment (so the same IOH/controller or switch). What is the topology of your system?

Comment: That isn't what I am asking. How are the GPUs on a single node connected together?